# Thread safety in java using XL work sheet

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a web application and I am accessing it by a web browser.  In the browser, I am having a submit button.  After clicking the submit button, a thread is invoked and it goes to Database, picks 20,0000 records and writes those records to a XL sheet.  What happens if I close the browser before the XL file got saved by the thread and why?